# make_tuple with template parameters does not compile

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples, rvalue-reference

Consider this code:

```
#include <tuple>

int main()
{
    int i;
    long k;

    auto tup1 = std::make_tuple<long>(i);   // Compiles
    auto tup2 = std::make_tuple<int>(k);    // Compiles
    auto tup3 = std::make_tuple<int>(i);    // Does not compile
    auto tup4 = std::make_tuple<int>(i+0);  // Compiles
    auto tup5 = std::make_tuple(i);         // Compiles
}
```

Why does `auto tup3 = ...` not compile? Apparently, `make_tuple<int>(...)` wants an rvalue reference as its argument; but why?

(I'm using GCC 6.1.0.)

Comment: You are not supposed to specify template type arguments in `make_tuple`, as otherwise you force types that cannot bind to the arguments

Comment: As stated above you shouldn't specify template type arguments. If you want to make i an rvalue just use std::move. This would compile:    
    
    auto tup3 = std::make_tuple<int>(std::move(i));

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`std::make_tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/make_tuple) and `std::make_pair` are designed to deduce template parameters (among other things, like unpacking reference wrappers). Providing them explicitly is a mistake.

In this particular case, it's because template deduction for rvalues yields their type, analogous to this example:

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T&&);

foo(42); // foo<int>(int&&)
int i{};
foo(i); // foo<int&>(int&) // after reference collapsing
```

and that's why `make_tuple<int>(...)` wants a rvalue reference to its argument.

If you want to force conversions, all you need to say is

```
auto tup1 = std::tuple<long>(i);
```